# Center all same theorem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ntheorem

I would like to know if it's possible right from the definition of a theorem to center it :

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
{

{
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\small}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremsymbol{C.Q.F.D.}
\newtheorem*{dem}{Démonstration}
}

}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

The code produces this : [image]

My goal is to have all same type of theorem to be centered.
Like this :

[image]

Comment: Not using your setup. Instead one could tie into `\begin{dem}` and `\end{dem}` (via something like [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)). However, could you supply the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that they can work with? It should show the current output as well as your expected output, rather than just code snippets.

Comment: Sure I will do it. But the fact is that I've seen this effect on a book (written with LaTeX for sure) and I don't really know how to reproduce it.

Comment: For the community's use, wrap the whole thing in a `center` environment and see what the output looks like. If it works for you, then that could be automated. If it doesn't, explain what should be different and perhaps include a screen shot (picture of some kind) of what it *should* look like.

Comment: I added the result of the posted code to explain myself.

Comment: Do you only want indentation on the left? This can be done with `\theoremindent <dimension>` before `\newtheorem*`. Notice the lack of curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to tie into the `\begin{dem}` and `\end{dem}` components of your theorem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem,etoolbox,changepage,lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\small}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremsymbol{C.Q.F.D.}
\newtheorem*{dem}{Démonstration}
% Center theorem with respect to text block (2em indent on both sides)
\AtBeginEnvironment{dem}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{2em}}
\AtEndEnvironment{dem}{\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{dem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{dem}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

`adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) is a list-like environment which is used to indent from either side and allows for breaking across the page boundary. You can adjust the `2em` measure to suit your needs.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for !
Thanks a lot for your help !